# cssnano removes "all" attribute from css @media query

Tags: css, media-queries, cssnano

I am curious if what cssnano does to media queries is ok. In my css file, I have.

```
@media all and ( min-width: 600px) {}
```

After running my css through cssnano, it turns it to this >

```
@media ( min-width: 600px) {}
```

Is this safe to use in production? I can't seem to find anywhere where it says not having the "all" attribute makes the browser default to all or if not having it is a bad thing for sending the file to production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author; yes, it's valid. I'll refer you to the original issue but in a nutshell:

> Per the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) (example 5):
>
> > I.e. these are identical:
> >
> > ```
> > @media all and (min-width:500px) { … }
> > @media (min-width:500px) { … }
> > ```
> >
> > As are these:
> >
> > ```
> > @media (orientation: portrait) { … }
> > @media all and (orientation: portrait) { … }
> > ```
>
> It seems to me that those could be stripped...[snip]

https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano/issues/215

Comment: Thank you @ben appreciate the information. Quick question.  If I'm reading all the Information right, by not using only or all in the stylesheet makes the file media queries better compatible with older browsers since they can't process the "only" or "all" portion and won't ready the query. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: I remember that being the case but I don't know if my memory serves me well on this issue; digging into the specification as far back as 2001 does indeed list "only" as part of the syntax of a media query - https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-mediaqueries-20010404/#media0 - but I don't have a source for its support. The best source for media queries in general is http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries; I wouldn't worry too much about old browser support these days, for IE if you need it then conditional comments still work well.

Comment: Just seen this wrt spec: "The keywords "only" and "not" are allowed in the media query as a way to avoid that legacy User Agents apply the style sheet without the device fulfilling the other conditions of the media query. This will work since "only" and "not" are not media types in HTML4." - so yes, indeed it is the case. :-)